# Best structure for memorizing user details and preferences

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a domain where each user has some information like
`height`, `weight`, `eye color`, `hair color`, `...` about himself, and very similar data about his ideal partner (`preferred height`, `preferred hair color`, `...`).

I have to match user respecting their characteristics and their preferences, keeping that in mind, what is the best structure in terms of performance?

I mean, I can design a table like: `Details(id, height, weight, eye_color, ...)` and a user table: `User(id, ..., details_id, preferences_details_id)` or a table like `Detail(id, type, value)` and a join table. There are even other approaches.

What would you choose and why?

Answer (score 1):

You have trampled into an area that can be the subject of almost religious fervor. Ardent "relationalists" would want you to put all columns in a single table. And for good reason. Supporters of entity-attribute-value models (EAV) have strong arguments in favor of that approach. And, there are hybrids between them. I would suggest that you start by researching EAV models. You may be able to figure out what is more appropriate for your particular environment.

Comment: sorry, I thought it was a kind of question where was possible to give an answer based on fact (performance test, or something similar)

Comment: @marka.thore . . . I would encourage you to ask another question, with some more specifics about the attributes and the types of queries you want to run.  I think you have a valid problem for Stack Overflow.  You happened to phrase it in such a way where you asked for an opinion instead of the better solution to your problem among several options.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what you want to do with that data

`Details(id, height, weight, eye_color, ...)`

This would be ok if the number of details is constant and for some reason you dont want to put it inside user model

`Detail(id, type, value)`

This approach is better if the number of details can change, as you won't need to modify the database "ever", all changes in number of details/types of details/possible values can be handled in code. The difference is that whenever you want to add a Detail, you would instert a default value for everybody instead of just adding a column.

In terms of performance, joining 2 tables will always be slower than selecting from a single table to some extent.